# How to use onclick with a textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css

i want to be able to make a div pop up when the user clicks on a textarea. Code:

CSS :

```
#comment{
    width: 500px;
    height:500px;
    background-color: black;
    position: fixed;
    left: 250px;
    top: 250px;
    float: left;
    display: none;
}
```

JS :

```
function comment() {
            if (document.getElementById('comment').style.display = 'none') {
                document.getElementById('comment').style.display = "inline";
                document.getElementById('container').style.opacity = opacity = 0.1;
            }

        }
```

HTML :

```
<input type="text" id="textarea" value="Comment..." style="color: #808080;" onclick="comment();">
<div id="comment"></div>
```

After reading the 3 comments below, i have fixed my problem, but now i want the div id="comment" to pop up in the middle(which it has) with everything else behind it faded out.

The code above makes everything go faded. div id="comment" is inside the #container, but is there anyway to stop this one from fading out with everything?

Comment: We need to see the script too.

Comment: Please set up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) were we can reproduce. Also share your debugging efforts.

Answer (score 4):

You forgot the `"` at the end of the attribute value for `style`. The `onclick` attribute name is therefore treated as part of the `style` attribute value.

This would have been picked up if you had used [a validator](http://validator.w3.org).

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" id="textarea" value="Comment..." style="color: #808080; onclick="comment();">
```

You are missing a closing quote after your `style="color: #808080;`

BTW, the code highlighter here pointed that out to me.  If you are using any kind of programmer's editor with syntax highlighting, it would have pointed it out to you as well.

Answer (score 1):

You have lots of errors in your code.

1. " mentioned by @Quentin
2. You need to use `getComputedStyle` to get actual style.
3. `document.getElementById('comment').style.display == "";` is meaningless. You need to use `=` instead of `==` and you need to specify a correct display `'block'`.

Code

```
function comment() {
    var comment = document.getElementById('comment');
    if (getComputedStyle(comment).display == 'none') {
        comment.style.display = 'block';
    }   
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/uvnhtmtv/

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me. I have only learned javascript for three days so im still very bad at it.